# Force PDF file download using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, pdf

i am using Apache as backend server and nginx as frontend server. I need to make PDF files downloadable (at this moment they are opening in a browser window).

Here's a link:

```
<a href="http://domain.com/files/teltomat.pdf" target="">link</a>
```

Here's what i have tried so far in my .htaccess file:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(pdf)$">
   ForceType application/octet-stream
   Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

Didn't work, just opens the file in a browser.

```
AddType application/force-download pdf
```

Didn't work.

```
AddType application/octet-stream .pdf
```

Didn't work.

**UPDATE**

Tried: `wget --server-response -O /dev/null http://domain.com/files/teltomat.pdf`

And got response:

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Server: nginx
  Date: Wed, 24 Sep 2014 17:40:54 GMT
  Content-Type: application/pdf
  Content-Length: 3116445
  Last-Modified: Wed, 24 Sep 2014 13:28:07 GMT
  Connection: keep-alive
  Keep-Alive: timeout=60
  ETag: "5422c6e7-2f8d9d"
  Expires: Thu, 31 Dec 2037 23:55:55 GMT
  Cache-Control: max-age=315360000
  Accept-Ranges: bytes
Length: 3116445 (3,0M) [application/pdf]
Saving to: ‘/dev/null’
```

Comment: I don't think this has any relation to Laravel.

Comment: Have you verified the headers make it to the browser, e.g. with `wget --server-response -O /dev/null http://domain.com/files/teltomat.pdf` or the Windows equivalent? IME, browsers will not content-sniff.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the HTML5 solution of adding a "download" instead of "target":

```
<a href="http://domain.com/files/teltomat.pdf" download="teltomat.pdf">link</a>
```

As it looks like the server's end is doing the right thing (by making the disposition "attachment") but maybe the browser is deciding on its own that it can handle PDF's inline and opens a new window instead.